# Show parents of uncommitted merge in git

Tags: git

How can I see the parents of an uncommitted merge in git?  I can see one parent by doing `git log -1` but how do I see the other parent?

This is easy to do in Mercurial:

```
$ hg parents
changeset:   2:b65656dbfff6
tag:         tip
parent:      0:1806d848df54
user:        Stephen Rasku 
date:        Tue Nov 27 10:14:31 2012 -0800
summary:     c

changeset:   1:9aaa22944f41
user:        Stephen Rasku 
date:        Tue Nov 27 10:14:01 2012 -0800
summary:     b
```

Is there anything equivalent in git?  I know you can see the parents of a committed merge in git.  This is specifically to see the parents of an uncommitted merge.

Comment: `cat .git/MERGE_HEAD` will show you the commit IDs that you're merging into HEAD.  `cat .git/HEAD` will, of course, show you HEAD.

Comment: That works.  You can get one head using `git log -1` and the other head using `git log -1 \`cat .git/MERGE_HEAD\``.  If you put it as an answer, I will accept it.  Otherwise I will do it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sources of an uncommitted merge are stored in `.git/MERGE_HEAD`.  If you are performing an octopus merge, you will have multiple commit IDs in this file, newline delimited.  The target of the merge, of course, `HEAD`.

If you want a detailed output, similar to the example you provided from Mercurial, you can feed that into `git log`, as you noted.  It may be easiest to write a shell script to handle this.

If you were to name this script `git-parents`, and place it in your path, you could simply run `git parents` to get a similar experience to what you described:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --no-pager log -1

WORKDIR=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
if [ -f "${WORKDIR}/.git/MERGE_HEAD" ]; then
    for a in `cat "${WORKDIR}/.git/MERGE_HEAD" | xargs` ; do
        git --no-pager log -1 $a
    done
fi
```

Comment: Why are you piping to cat?  I tried the script with it both present and absent and it doesn't seem to make a difference in my simple (non-octopus) test case.

Comment: `git log`, for me anyway, always sends to `$PAGER`.  For me, `$PAGER` is `less` which will always stop at EOF, even if number of lines is less than your display size.  `more` would probably not have this restriction, and I have no earthly idea what happens with msys or cygwin on Win32.  Piping to cat will avoid pagination.

Comment: Aha, there's a `--no-pager` option that is not present in the man page, but is referenced at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824165/git-for-windows-paging which would be a superior solution.  (Edited.)

Comment: I noticed your solution doesn't work if you run it where you are not doing a merge.  I suggested a solution but it was rejected.  Did you see the edit?

Comment: I did not.  What do you mean "run it where you are not doing a merge"?

Comment: For mercurial, if you do `hg parents` and you're not doing a merge you will get a single parent listed.  In your script, it throws an error because `MERGE_HEAD` doesn't exist in that case.  Wrapping your loop in an if statement that tests for the existence of the file would allow your script to be run on any repository.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Sorry, I'm not too familiar with Hg, but that makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

I have no repo to try it here, but won't this work?

```
$ git show HEAD^ # shows first parent
$ git show HEAD^2 # shows second parent
$ git show HEAD^3 # and so on...
```

Do yo need to show *all* parents, no matter how many? I suppose you can do some scripting with `git log -1 --parents` or something like that.

Comment: That would show the parents of a commit, not the parents of an uncommitted merge.