# Git for windows paging

Tags: windows, git, version-control

Whenever I  execute `git log` command it cannot be terminated. If I do Ctrl + C it exits paging environment but if I start to type anything it starts `git log` command again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as mentioned already, `git log -X` will limit your output to the last X commits.

Git log and other git commands invoke the `less` command. This is the pager. To get help with the pager, type ? or h when looking at the output. You will now see the help for the `less` command. Quitting less is easy, just type `q`.

If you don't want log to use a pager utility, you can instruct git not to use it with:

```
git --no-pager log
```

Git log has a lot of options. To get a quick overview of what has happened, I use

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

Decorate can be set to be enabled by default through config so you don't have to issue it.

If you think that's a lot to write on the command line, you're right! Bash has a quick remedy for that: `CTRL-R`. Press that and start typing 'graph'. You should get the last time that you typed that long command. This is one reason I don't bother with git aliases; it's easy to search your command history which persists from session to session.

Further, you can limit the output of `git log` to a particular author or particular date range, etc.

Have fun exploring and stick to the command line. It's what git was meant to be used on. You will also be introduced to a lot of excellent bash techniques that will help you a ton as you get going further with git.

Comment: less is quite useful. Take 10 minutes to explore it's search and other capabilities. Cheers :)

Comment: Please update. git log does not know "--online" any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of commits to be shown with:

```
 git log -n 10
```

To limit only to the last 10 commits.

You can use also some kind of graphic interface for git, like gitk or [tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/) or [git-cola](http://git-cola.github.com/).
Check for other gui clients [here](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis).

Comment: this can be shortened to `git log -10`